# Migrating mongo db users to auth0 accounts

Tags: mongodb, migration, auth0

I am currently working on a project that involves migrating users from MongoDB to Auth0.

I am getting this error whenever I try to login using auth0 console

```
Request to Webtask exceeded allowed execution time
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
function login(email, password, callback) {
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://user:user@cluster0.vrmsqcv.mongodb.net/');

  client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    const db = client.db('test_db');
    const users = db.collection('users');

    users.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
      if (err || !user) {
        client.close();
        return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isValid) {
        client.close();

        if (err || !isValid) return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

        return callback(null, {
          user_id: user._id.toString(),
          nickname: user.nickname,
          email: user.email
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I am seeking your expertise to help me understand how to modify this code to accommodate the migration of users from MongoDB to Auth0 seamlessly.